# Java MouseListener graphics implementation

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, mouselistener

So I am trying to implement a mouse listener into my program, I got the mouseListener to work but not the graphics. I am trying to find a way to draw a blue circle every time the mouse is clicked on the JPANEL, the only problem is I can not seem to get a good call for the Graphics (that I have tried to name g).

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



class moveItMon extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

    public moveItMon() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        requestFocus();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        movetehMon(e);
    }

    public void movetehMon(MouseEvent e){
        int x = e.getX();
        int y = e.getY();
        System.out.println("(" + x + "," + y + ")");
        paintMon(x,y);
    }
    public void paintMon( int x, int y){
        Graphics g = new Graphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillOval(x,y,20,20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] s) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("moveItMon");
        f.getContentPane().add(new moveItMon());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }


}
```

Comment: just a tip, according to java code conventions class name should start with a Upper case letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Graphics g = new Graphics();` isn't going to work (as I'm sure you're aware) as the class is abstract.

Custom painting in Swing is done by overriding the `paintComponent` of a component that extends from `JComponent` (like `JPanel`) and using the supplied `Graphics` context to paint to.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more details

You should also beware that painting is a destructive process, meaning that each time `paintComponent` is called, you are expected to update everything that you need painted.

Comment: Thanks yet again. One more question that may sound silly, is there a way to implement a drawing(which I wish to use as a hit box) that doesn't change using the graphics component?

Comment: There are at least two ways to achieve it.  The first is store each shape you generate in some kind of `List` and iterate this list each time the `paintComponent` is called.  This would require to store information about color and other properties along with the shape. The other is to use a `BufferedImage` as the primary canvas, paint to this directly and when `paintComponent` is called, paint the image to the `Graphics` context